# Numpy vectorize multidimensional function (or, building feature planes for a neural network)

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, computer-vision

Say we have N color (RGB) images of size 100x100 stored in A[N][100][100][3].
So:

```
Channel 0 = R
Channel 1 = G
Channel 2 = B
```

What is the most efficient way of building some other channels using numpy? For example, let's define:

```
Channel 3 = R + G * 0.5
Channel 4 = If B > 128 Then 1 Else 0
Channel 5 = If R == 100 Then 1 Else 0
Channel 6 = If (R + G) > B Then 1 Else 0
```

In other words, we would like to get A[N][100][100][7] with the extra 4 channels built using the above rules for each pixel.

It seems that is no general method to vectorize such operations in numpy, but I think there should be a method for the simple case here. Moreover, what will be the fastest method when N is large (>10000) ?

Answer (score 0):

There are comparatively straight-forward ways, for example:

```
rgb = np.random.random((1,2,2,3))
r,g,b = np.transpose(rgb, (3,0,1,2))
np.r_["-1, 4, 0", rgb, r+g*0.5, b>128, r==100, (r+g)>b]
# array([[[[ 0.64715017,  0.45204962,  0.28497451,  0.87317498,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
#         [ 0.51238478,  0.62095329,  0.9339249 ,  0.82286142,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]],

#        [[ 0.29647208,  0.81635033,  0.76079918,  0.70464724,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
#         [ 0.3307639 ,  0.1878836 ,  0.04642399,  0.4247057 ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]]]])
```

The `r_` concatenation operator is a bit cryptic, if a 3-int-string is passed as first argument it means concatenation axis, depth to promote operands to, axis to align unpadded dimensions to.

One could probably save a bit of peak memory by preallocating and computing the intermediates sequentially.

Speed-wise I don't see any obvious improvements over the above.